# B2C Orchestationstep phone verify default value

Tags: mobile, default-value, azure-ad-b2c, verify

I have this orchestation steps:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PhoneFactor-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

this technical profile for first orchestation step:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
      <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />

      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

and this technical profile for second orchestation step:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify">
          <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.phonefactor</Item>
            <Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="UserId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="Verified.OfficePhone" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_655ae1ae68ed4c84a951961db1d40222_doblefactor" />
            <!-- TODO: OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userAssertedPhoneNumber" /-->
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-MFA" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

I need to use my mobile phone information as default

[image]

Do you have an example for this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you already have the authentication phone number for the end user and if so, then you don't want to prompt the end user to enter it again?

Comment: I have the authentication phone number in user profile, and the user can enter it again or modify it in the phone number textbox

Comment: Hi ChrisHUM, Can you also show the orchestration step #1, and the technical profile associated with it?

Comment: Hi, the question was updated

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the "strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" claim in the first orchestration step.

Add the "strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" claim as an `<OutputClaim />` to the "AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" technical profile.

Add the same claim as an `<OutputClaim />` to the "LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" technical profile.

It should then be passed as an `<InputClaim />` to the "PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" technical profile.

Comment: Can you please clarify @ChrisHUMChrisHum?

Answer (score -1):

I think whatyou want to do is replicate the answer to this question except change mobile to email

[Triggering email verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351072/triggering-email-verification/44429492#44429492)